# Prevent increase file while encrypting with crypto

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, audio, encryption

I'm new using Crypto library on node to encrypt my audio files. Below follow the code:

```
const cipher = Crypto.createCipher("aes-256-cbc", PASSWORD);
const encrypted = Buffer.concat([cipher.update(Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(data), "utf8")), cipher.final()]);
fs.writeFileSync(musica.path, encrypted);
```

My original file size has 9.8 MB but encrypted file has a size of 42 MB. How can I prevent it? Why file is increased?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The code you've provided doesn't have any issues that would result in the symptom you're describing. Please [edit] your question to show a complete and verifiable example.

Comment: @ArtjomB. is it better now?

Comment: You haven't edited your code. So, no. Please see [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Can you provide example inputs that show this behavior at a small scale?